# How to obtain the limits of integration ($0$ to $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4kt}}$) in a solution to the Diffusion Equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Our purpose in this section is to solve the problem
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> u_{t} &=k u_{x x} \quad(-\infty<x<\infty, 0<t<\infty) \\
> u(x, 0) &=\phi(x) .
> \end{aligned}
> $$

> We'll look for $Q(x, t)$ of the special form
> $$
> Q(x, t)=g(p) \quad \text { where } p=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4 k t}}
> $$

> From $$
> g^{\prime \prime}+2 p g^{\prime}=0
> $$
> This $\mathrm{ODE}$ is easily solved using the integrating factor $\exp (\int 2 p d p)=\exp (\left(p^{2}\right))$. We get $g^{\prime}(p)=c_{1} \exp \left(-p^{2}\right)$ and
> $$
> Q(x, t)=g(p)=c_{1} \int e^{-p^{2}} d p+c_{2}
> $$
> We find a completely explicit formula for $Q$. We've just shown that
> $$
> Q(x, t)=c_{1} \int_{0}^{x / \sqrt{4 k t}} e^{-p^{2}} d p+c_{2}
> $$

I do not understand how to find the limits of integration in the solution to the diffusion equation Q(x,t). I believe that you can only write Q(x,t) as an indefinite integral rather a definite integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually make the limits definite right from the start if you want. You multiply both sides by $e^{p^2}$:

$$g'' e^{p^2} + 2p g' e^{p^2} = 0 \\
(g' e^{p^2})' = 0.$$

Now you can integrate on both sides over whatever range you want. In this case they're using $0$ to $p$, which should really be done with its own dummy variable of integration, say $u$:

$$\int_0^p (g'(u) e^{u^2})' du = \int_0^p 0 du \\
g'(p) e^{p^2} - g'(0) = 0 \\
g'(p) = e^{-p^2} g'(0) \\
\int_0^p g'(u) du = \int_0^p e^{-u^2} g'(0) du \\
g(p) - g(0) = g'(0) \int_0^p e^{-u^2} du \\
g(p) = g(0) + g'(0) \int_0^p e^{-u^2} du.$$

Indefinite integration is almost never technically necessary, definite integrals with variable limits are pretty much always an alternative.